# Would this character be overpowered? If so, how could I balance him?

Tags: dnd-5e, polymorph, half-elf

The character is a half-elf (a Fey Wanderer ranger) by physical standards, using half-elf bonuses and all proficiencies except language. (he can speak Common and Draconic)

(TL,DR: dragon egg sold to evil guy, dragon kills evil guy, dragon cursed to become the evil guy, is not having any of that)

He is actually a bronze dragon. His mother was killed by adventurers, who sold the eggs on the black market. His lot was to be sold to an evil wizard who experimented and tortured him. Well, dragons tend to get BIG. VERY BIG. When he grew big enough to do some damage, by the end of that day, his brass scales were red with blood. The wizard, with his dying breath, cursed him with a powerful Polymorph spell to take on his visage and live as the wizard did-alone, dirty, and in misery. The now-half-elf-dragon was not having that. He decided not to do that, and set off on his own. He has dedicated his life to protecting nature and creatures from suffering the same fate as him.

Edgy, I know. **But, I was thinking, he could use his highest-level spell slot to breathe lightning (like a dragonborn) once per long rest. Would that be overpowered, or balanced?**

Comment: Lots of questions here! I assume you're going for backstory and not actually trying to play a dragon PC, and for that reason you're ignoring the duration of Polymorph, the existence of Remove Curse, how an egg raised by a half-elf learned draconic, and a few others. With that assumption in mind, is your **only** balance question that of allowing a PC to use a dragon's breath weapon once per long rest?

Comment: You need to clarify the question. While backstory may be interesting, for balance issues it matters little - how character acquired some ability. If question is only about adding a single limited in use ability - it would, of course, increase character's power, but not too much.